# How to Install Photoshop in Ubuntu OS?

Tags: photoshop, ubuntu-12.04, software-design

Hello Any One Have You Idea How to Install Photoshop in Ubuntu OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install Photoshop CS4 in Ubantu Using Wine & PlayOnlineLinux.

So please refer [LINK](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/01/how-to-install-photoshop-cs4-in-ubuntu.html) given step by step guide line.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try Gimp In ubuntu instead Ubuntu Software Center -> Gimp
, if you still want photoshop try installing Wine(used to run windows apps in ubuntu/linux) and install photoshop using wine

You can also try out [Online Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/tools)